# How to add a frequency offset to a buffer of MPSK signal for simulation purposes?

Tags: digital-communications, frequency, doppler, baseband

I need to simulate some channel effect to a buffer of MPSK signal. How to add a frequency offset to a buffer of baseband MPSK signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the time domain samples by a time-varying complex exponential to effect a (cyclic) shift in the frequency domain.

$$y[n] = x[n]\cdot e^{j\pi \frac{f_{offset}}{F_s/2}n}$$

Where $f_{offset} \in \left(-\dfrac{F_s}{2}, \dfrac{F_s}{2}\right)$.

This is a result of the Shift Theorem for the DFT.